Relation between rotation groups and spin groups
Sorry if very dumb question. What exactly is the relation between rotation groups and spin groups? I've heard that the spin groups are the double cover of rotation groups but ks there a more precise and "computational" mathematical relation?
I read that
$ \operatorname{SO}(n) \simeq \operatorname{Spin}(n) \times \operatorname{Spin}(n) $
Which in turn implies
$ \mathfrak{so}(n) \simeq \mathfrak{spin}(n) \oplus \mathfrak{spin}(n) $
However, does this mean i can take a representation of $ \mathfrak{spin}(n) $ and direct sum with itself to get a representation of $ \mathfrak{so}(n) $ ?
The whole motivation behind this is to get elements of $  \operatorname{SO}(3) $ from $  \operatorname{SU}(2) $ and ultimately, elements of $ \operatorname{SO}^+(1,3) $ from $ \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) $ since $ \operatorname{SU}(2) = \operatorname{Spin}(2) $ and $ \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) = \operatorname{Spin}(1,3) $

$SO(n)$ is not the product of two copies of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$.

It is definitely not true that $ \mathfrak{so}(n) = \mathfrak{spin}(n) \oplus \mathfrak{spin}(n) $. Indeed $ \mathfrak{so}(n) = \mathfrak{spin}(n) $. So they have all the same representations. The groups don't necessarily have the same property as not every Lie algebra representation lifts to a Lie group representation for a given group
A double cover means that there is a 2 to 1 mapping between the two groups (indeed a continuous group homomorphism). In fact $SO(n)$ is a quotient of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ by a discrete subgroup of the centre. Such a quotient doesn't change the Lie algebra at all as the two groups are locally isomorphic around the identity.
So if you want to get elements of $SO(n)$ from elements of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ all you need to do is find out what this 2 to 1 function is. Remembering that it must be a surjective group homomorphism and its kernel must be a discrete subgroup of the centre you should be able to find that yourself.

Kernel =$ {\pm1}$?

@J.W.Tanner yes for both the map from $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and the one from $\operatorname{SU}(2)$
